# Why does my parametric trigonometric function appears to be a polynomial?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, polynomials, parametric

I was fooling around with $(\cos^2(t),\sin^2(at))$ with varying values of $a$, and found that if $a=3$ then $(\cos^2(t),\sin^2(3t))$ gives the graph of $y=-16x^3+24x^2-9x+1$ on the domain $[0,1]$

[image: -16x^3+24x^2-9x+1]

The calculator won't do parametrics but it just looks like the graph from 0 to 1.
Eliminating the parameter gave me $\sin ^2\left(3\cos ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)\right)$

Why is this true? And, how can I solve $\sin ^2\left(3\cos ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)\right)=-16x^3+24x^2-9x+1$ to prove that the Cartesian form is equal to the polynomial?

Comment: It's not the same thing, but $T_n(x)=\cos(n \arccos(x))$ are the so-called Chebyshev polynomials, which are indeed polynomials even though they don't look that way. In view of that I am not surprised that $\sin(3 \arccos(\sqrt{x}))^2$ turns out to be a polynomial.

Comment: You can use angle addition formulas for $\sin(3u)$. Then letting$ u= \cos^{-1}(\sqrt{x})$, you'll need that $\sin(\cos^{-1}(w))=\sqrt{1-w^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$\begin{align*}y=\sin^2 3t &= (3\sin t - 4\sin^3 t)^2 \\ &= \sin^2 t(3-4\sin^2 t)^2 \\& = (1-\cos^2 t)(3-4(1-\cos^2 t))^2 \\ & = (1-x)(4x-1)^2 \\ & =-16x^3+24x^2-9x+1\end{align*}$$

where we derived $\sin 3t = 3\sin t - 4\sin^3 t$ either by expanding $e^{3it}$ and taking imaginary parts or by expanding $\sin 3t = \sin (2t + t)$ and then expanding $\sin 2t$.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this property is the tip of an iceberg. Here is a generalization.

There exists a family of polynomials $U_n(x)$ (called Chebyshev polynomials *of the second kind* (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html)) allowing to express, for any $n>0$,

$$\sin((n+1)\theta)=\sin\theta \ \times U_n(\cos \theta)$$

Thus, by squaring both sides, for any $n$,

$$\tag{1}\sin^2((n+1)\theta)=(1-\cos^2\theta) \times [U_n(\cos\theta)]^2$$

which is a polynomial is $\cos \theta$.

Here are the first $U_n(x)$:

$$\begin{array}{l}U_1(x)=2x\\U_2(x)=-1 + 4\,x^2\\U_3(x)=-4\,x + 8\,x^3\\U_4(x)=1 - 12\,x^2 + 16\,x^4,\\
  U_5(x)=6x - 32\,x^3 + 32\,x^5,\\U_6(x)=-1 + 24\,x^2 - 80\,x^4 + 64\,x^6 \end{array}$$
etc.

Let us see what formula (1) gives with $n=2$:

$$\sin^2(3\theta)=(1-\cos^2\theta) \times (4\,\cos^2\theta - 1)^2$$

$$=1 - 9\,\cos^2\theta + 24\,\cos^4\theta - 16\,\cos^6\theta$$

as desired.

The $U_n(x)$ constitute an important family of orthogonal polynomials, with many properties, but that's another story...

Comment: In order to get to the polynomial from here, you would have to substitute cos^2(theta) for x, why is that possible?

Comment: It means that you can find such a $\theta$ only for $0 \leq x \leq 1$. The figure you have given is for an extended range where $x$ can take for example negative values, which is impossible for the "square of something".

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin^2(3t)=1-\cos^2(3t)=1-(4\cos^3 t-3\cos t)^2=-16(\cos^2 t)^3+24 (\cos^2t)^2-9\cos^2t+1$$